# print all(non-hidden)files in subdirectory of current directory that end with .c

Tags: linux

`find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name "*.c"`
It was failed.Can anyone tell me the correct one?

Thank you.

Comment: `ls */*.c`. If that is not what you want then please make your requirements clearer.

Comment: You don't need to specify non-hidden. A wildcard won't match a name that begins with `.` unless the wildcard itself begins with `.`.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
ls ./*.c
```

this is the simplest way

Answer (score 0):

Please work on your own on CS246 A1Q1.

As the solution post above. 
1) ls*/*.c 
This solution will not distinguish file v.s. dir.
In other word if you have a dir in any subdir that has a name with *.c will also be printed.

2) find ./ -name *.c
Find key word cannot be used for A1Q1.